# reading from doc file to CKEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, ms-word, ckeditor

I integrate CKEditor into my aspx file for client use. The user can select the file to upload and then click button "preview" to view the content of the file before uploading. The content will then be read and displayed into CKEditor.

It is ok when reading from a notepad file, but when reading from a docx file, I got the font error. It contains characters like "+�"_W��Z5��������ړ�l�G��g��Q��.�)��{?����ٴ�#�����y5aX锶˚���,/YQX%Zg�f��jv�e:�x��m�� ".

This is the code snippet I used:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div>
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="400px">
                </CKEditor:CKEditorControl> 
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Preview"
                onclick="previewbutton_Click" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

and code behind:

```
if (fileupload.PostedFile != null && fileupload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileupload.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            CKEditor1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Anyone please help me with this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A docx file is not a text file. You need a text file or a html file if you wanna display it in  CKEditor.
You can convert a .docx file to an HTML file on the client.

Comment: so it means that I have to convert the docx file to HTML file and then display the HTML file in CKEditor?

Comment: Yes, that would be an option. But you either have to do it manually on the client (eg. desktop) or have a component on the server that converts a docx into an html. We use Aspose.Words for this.

Comment: No it will not, you cannot upload a docx file and show it as is on the CKEDITOR

Comment: So if I convert the docx file to a HTML file and then read from the HTML file, will it still keep the original format as it was in the docx file?

Comment: not 100%. Depends on the word file and what features you used there.

Comment: Is there any way that I use the paste function of CKEditor to load a HTML file automatically without manually selecting the file? Thank you.